# What should I do when FBInstant ad "NO FILL" error shows

Tags: facebook, facebook-audience-network, facebook-instant-games

I'm developing a messenger game using latest FBInstant SDK and when I try to show ads, most of the time, the loadAsync() returns "no fill" error. I'm testing with my friend's account and other games successfully display ads while my game always get "no fill" error. I've chosen "Accept Any Price" setting for my ad placements in my fb dev account settings. My questions are

1. Why is my game always ( or most of the time ) getting "no fill" error while other games are successfully displaying ads with the same account? Is it because it is not released yet?
2. What should I do when I get the "no fill" error when loadAsync()? I've load the ad with the same id again and again but it results in "no fill" 20 times in a row. sometimes never filled. When I try to get a new ad instance everytime the ad fails to load, it end up calling 3 new ad instances and get the error "too many requests". Can anyone pls explain me what you do after getting the "no fill" error

thanks.

Comment: Check this for no-fill reasons:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq/#faq_1204719862895859

Answer (score 0):

You will get a `NO_FILL` for any user who is not a developer/tester of the app if you have not had your placements approved in Monetization Manager.

If you get a `NO_FILL` return code from `loadAsync` there is likely no value in trying again — if we didn't have an ad to show the user it is unlikely that will change in a couple of seconds.

Comment: How do you get your placements approved ?